# How to see what Axis2 sends and receives?

Tags: java, http, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I have Axis2 created web service client. This service uses both SSL and WS-Security so I use `rampart`. I think that my client sends correct query, but I got exception:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.checkMustUnderstand(AxisEngine.java:97)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:163)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at pl.firstdata.www.wdx.business.card.CardServiceStub.getBalance(CardServiceStub.java:1570)
at pl.firstdata.www.wdx.business.card.wdx_client.main(wdx_client.java:164)
```

Is there any way to see "bare" query and response with HTTP headers?

While this service use SSL I think I cannot use HTTP monitor, and this should be done by axis2 after "applying" WS-Security but before SSL. I can enable such logging on my emulator (without SSL) and it seems like that:

```
POST /webservices/emu/get_info.hdb HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Axis2
Host: 127.0.0.1:8765
Content-Length: 4585

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EncKeyId-0D71FF61F3796881F812803190645315"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" /><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:KeyIdentifier ...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [stunel](http://www.stunnel.org/) with [tcpmon](https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/). Steps:

1. my `axis2` app do normal HTTP query; this query is send to `tcpmon`
2. `tcpmon` logs it and sends query to `stunel`
3. `stunel` adds SSL and sends endcrypted query to destination server
4. `stunel` receives encrypted response, decrypts it and sends back to `tcpmon`
5. `tcpmon` logs decrypted response and sends it to my `axis2` app

Answer (score 2):

Use the tcpmon tool for this.

Please note that in most Linux based installations, this will most probably be built for you. Once you've done with the building process, you can find the executable at ${AXIS2C_HOME}/bin/tools on Linux, or at %AXIS2C_HOME%\bin\tools on MS Windows.

Comment: I already use it, but not for services protected by SSL. Service provider tells that he cannot disable SSL even for tests so I need other tools. Maybe axis2 have some option to see "bare" query and "bare" reply?

Comment: I belive fiddler can act as a man in the middle proxy even for ssl debugging. (fiddler is a proxy used for debugging http requests)

Comment: Thanks. As in my response I used stunel. It do not need .NET as fiddler2, and seems easy for somebody who use tcpmon.

Comment: @Michal, Hos do I configur axis to use fiddler2 as my proxy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284862/where-do-i-place-axis2-xml-to-be-read-by-a-jar-with-a-soap-client

Comment: I ended up using wireshark on windows since I had it installed.