# How to debug an https:// site in Eclipse with Zend debugger and PDT

Tags: ssl, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I have been successfully debugging several projects using Eclipse 3.4.1 with Zend Debugger and PDT.  I now have a site running locally using https://.  Have not been able to set a Debug Configuration in Eclipse that gets there.  any ideas?  Many thanks, Mary Edith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see what is send/received by your application, but HTTPS hides it, then you can use normal HTTP query with stunel which "adds" SSL to socket transmission. I use it to monitor my axis2 application: [How to see what Axis2 sends and receives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360595/how-to-see-what-axis2-sends-and-receives)

EDIT:

There is example in `stunnel` doc where client cannot use SSL: http://www.stunnel.org/examples/https_client.html

In your case you can configure `stunnel` like:

```
[https]
; https://www.mylocalsecuresite.com:443/myapp/AppService
accept  = 88
connect = www.mylocalsecuresite.com:443
```

Then in Eclipse dialog with URL use:

```
localhost:88
```

Communication between Eclipse and `stunnel` will be in plain text, but between `stunnel` and `www.mylocalsecuresite.com:443` will be encrypted.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't know how to apply this to my situation.

Comment: If you can debug HTTP then with stunel you can debug HTTPS which from you side will be HTTP: your program <-->HTTP<-->stunel<--HTTPS-->WebServer

Comment: Thanks for your help; I didn't see your answer until today.  I don't understand enough to follow this suggestion.  Where exactly do I put the "<-->HTTP<-->stunel<--HTTPS-->WebServer ".  In Eclipse Debug configuration?

Comment: No. If you have debugged HTTP then HTTPS encrypts input and output. If you want to see what your application sends and receives without encryption then put `stunel` between your application and apache or other https server.

Comment: http://localhost/mywebroot/stunnel/https://www.mylocalsecuresite.com? or http://localhost/mywebroot<-->stunnel<-->https://www.mylocalsecuresite.com?

Comment: There's a dialog in Eclipse to set up a server to debug.  THat's where I'm trying to put this.  for regular http, "http://localhost" or "http://www.mysite.com" work just fine.  I'm still not sure of the exact text you recommend.

Comment: Ok, I will try this later today.  I'm on a Mac, but found a place to download stunnel for mac.  I'm debugging ssl because a drupal site I'm working on has ssl protection of all the admin pages; I've created a local copy of the site including the ssl, and would so like debugger facility as I develop!!

Comment: I got this going!  Many thanks for your patience.  I now understand what stunnel is and what it does. Cheers to you!

Comment: No problem :) Stack overflow is helpful. You can accept my answer so it will not be listed as unanswered